# Vagrant Laravel Scotchbox - An error by vagrant up

Tags: laravel, vagrant

A Laravel project with Scotchbox, I will run my server by vagrant up.
When I run Vagrant up, I get the following error:

[image]

Can someone help me with this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved this long ago by rebooting the computer, entering the BIOS and enabling a virtualitzation option.

Depending en your hardware your BIOS panel looks diferent. But you should somewhere find an option named virtualization, once found, enable it and reboot.

http://druss.co/2015/06/fix-vt-x-is-not-available-verr_vmx_no_vmx-in-virtualbox/

Comment: Virtualization is all "enable" in my BIOS